# Clever, efficient way to reorder form arrays in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items on my web page that the user can dynamically add and remove from.  Each item resembles this:

```
<tr id="LELOC_0">
    <td>
        <label title="" for="LE">
            Legal Entity:</label>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="CAS.LERoles[0].LE" id="CAS_LERoles_0__LE" data-val-required="The Legal Entity field is required."
            data-val-number="The field Legal Entity must be a number." data-val="true" class="tinyText">
        <br>
        <label title="" for="LOC">
            Location:</label>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="CAS.LERoles[0].LOC" id="CAS_LERoles_0__LOC" data-val-required="The Location field is required."
            data-val-number="The field Location must be a number." data-val="true" class="tinyText">
    </td>
    <td>
        <label title="" for="APMasterRole">
            AP Master Role:</label>
        <select name="CAS.LERoles[0].APMasterRole" id="CAS_LERoles_0__APMasterRole">
            <option value="0" title="">None</option>
            <option value="1" title="">LBK</option>
            <option value="2" title="">General Manager</option>
            <option value="3" title="">Publisher</option>
            <option value="4" title="">RAM</option>
            <option value="5" title="">District Manager</option>
            <option value="6" title="">Corp0</option>
            <option value="7" title="">Corp1</option>
            <option value="8" title="">Corp2</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label title="" for="WebPortalRole">
            Web Portal Role:</label>
        <select name="CAS.LERoles[0].WebPortalRole" id="CAS_LERoles_0__WebPortalRole">
            <option value="0" title="">None</option>
            <option value="1" title="">Admin</option>
            <option value="2" title="">LBK</option>
            <option value="3" title="">PUB</option>
            <option value="4" title="">Security</option>
            <option value="5" title="">RAM</option>
            <option value="6" title="">CAS</option>
            <option value="7" title="">Site Data Entry</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label title="" for="AnyViewIDSRole">
            AnyView IDS Role:</label>
        <select name="CAS.LERoles[0].AnyViewIDSRole" id="CAS_LERoles_0__AnyViewIDSRole">
            <option value="0" title="">None</option>
            <option value="1" title="">Administrators</option>
            <option value="2" title="">All Access</option>
            <option value="3" title="">CORP</option>
            <option value="4" title="">GL</option>
            <option value="5" title="">LBK</option>
            <option value="6" title="">Other</option>
            <option value="7" title="">PUB</option>
            <option value="8" title="">RBK</option>
            <option value="9" title="">RM</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label title="" for="APMasterPurchaseApprover">
            AP Master Approver:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="CAS.LERoles[0].APMasterPurchaseApprover" id="CAS_LERoles_0__APMasterPurchaseApprover"
            data-val-requiredif-operator="EqualTo" data-val-requiredif-dependentvalue="LBK"
            data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty="APMasterRole" data-val-requiredif="If the user is in the AP Master LBK role, the AP Master Purchase Approver must be provided."
            data-val="true" class="smallText">
        <br>
        <label title="" for="WebPortalPurchaseApprover">
            Web Portal Approver:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="CAS.LERoles[0].WebPortalPurchaseApprover" id="CAS_LERoles_0__WebPortalPurchaseApprover"
            data-val-requiredif-operator="EqualTo" data-val-requiredif-dependentvalue="LBK"
            data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty="WebPortalRole" data-val-requiredif="If the user is in the Web Portal LBK role, the Web Portal Purchase Approver must be provided."
            data-val="true" class="smallText">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="deleteButton" id="btnDelete_0" type="button">
            Delete</button>
        <button class="addButton" id="btnAdd_0" type="button">
            Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The trick is, if the user deletes the item, I'd like to reorder the list so that when posting back to the server, there are no gaps in sequence numbers.  My first thought for this was to loop through all the `<tr>` elements and regex match/ replace the sequence numbers, but that seems really messy.  So I'm wondering, is there a nifty javascript/ jQuery way to make this simple?  Otherwise I may just say "screw it" and check for missing sequences on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the sequence numbers relevant in the page whilst they are editable? 
If not, just omit them and have them generated only when saving.

```
function generateItemsToSave() {
    var itemsToSave = [];
    jQuery('tr').each(function(pos, el) {
        var locData = {
          id: 'LELOC_' + itemsToSave.length,
          //Build rest of locData from el
        };
        itemsToSave.push(locData);
    });
    return itemsToSave;
}
saveItems(generateItemsToSave());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, they are... I need to be able to key off specific rows.

Comment: I'd probably use attributes `<tr class="LELOC" locref="blah1">` and then reference them via `locref` rather than depend on the id number (especially if the id is expected to change). That way you have a disconnect between how you access them in the page, and how they are subsequently saved, whilst still maintaining the ability to manipulate them in-page.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loop through all of the TR elements and update the id attribute, before the form post.

```
var newValue = "LELOC_";
$("tr").each(function(i, row) {
   $(row).attr("id", newValue + i);
});
```

Do that before the form submit, and it will change them all to be in sequence.

Comment: Well, the row ID is less worrying than the form input names.

Comment: Same would apply to the contents of each row. Just find the descendant elements and update their attributes as well. Otherwise, just set the values as you process the form on the server side.